# Set Facebook Timeline readonly via application

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline, readonly

Is it possible to set a users timeline readonly (so that nobody can post things on the user's timeline) using a Facebook Application? http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13259653/facebook_api.png

I couldn't find anything in the permissions but maybe someone could help https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope the api doesn't allow such things, you can't change a user's privacy settings.